# Should we change the "software recs" OT reason to point to the software recs SE?

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons, software-recs-se

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

But there is (at least in beta) [a software recommendations Stack Exchange site](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/). I'm tempted to stop using the official one and just use a custom reason pointing to the new SE site. Maybe it'd be better to change the wording in the official close reason to indicate the right place to go to get software recommendations.

Edit: This question already has an answer [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221970/changed-response-to-recommendation-questions). (Hat tip: Servy)

Comment: **Do not do that.** Unless you're linking to their help page and telling users about the rules and the need to read them, you're just sending an unknowledged user to another site where the question will be closed down.

Comment: I'm amused that this question is garnering downvotes on meta. Is it that I did poor research and the answer should be apparent, somewhere, or is it that my attempt to improve my understanding of this particular close reason is _actually_ not useful to myself (or to the people whose questions I vote to close)?

Comment: this would end in a next epic meta post, like [Please stop using Software Recs.SE as your toilet bowl](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73382/please-stop-using-programmers-se-as-your-toilet-bowl "just as it has been with Programmers")

Comment: "You have asked a question in a problem domain that I am not qualified in. I don't even know if your question is good or not in that context. I would like to send you to people who understand that problem domain better, but I have been informed that they would rather I not do that, so I will just close your question here and leave you swinging in the wind. Have a nice day."

Comment: @kojiro Downvotes are different on meta. If it's a [meta-tag:feature-request], in addition to the normal voting guidelines people also vote on if they like the idea or not. Don't take it personally; it's just people think this is a bad idea.

Comment: @hichris123 fair enough, but the downvote button just says what it always says, *This question does not show any research effort; It is unclear or not useful*. Hmmm. Perhaps I should open another feature request. >:)

Comment: @kojiro [Already done.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75049/change-upvote-downvote-tooltip-on-meta-sites) :P

Comment: @kojiro To be fair, this has been brought up quite a number of times.  You *didn't* do your research before asking this question.

Comment: @Servy Then this question should be closed as a dupe, or the answers below should link to relevant resources.

Comment: @kojiro It can't be closed as a dupe due to the meta.SO/meta.SE split.

Comment: @Servy Yes, there are questions about software recommendations in various forms, but as far as I have been able to tell there is no question on m.se m.so or m.sr.se asking to reconcile the existence of an external software recs se with this close reason on StackOverflow. Your assertion that I didn't do my research is unfounded.

Comment: @kojiro Just to get you started: [1](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221970/changed-response-to-recommendation-questions) [2](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228606/add-a-link-to-se-recommendations-to-the-off-topic-close-reason) [3](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178444/should-beta-sites-be-listed-for-migration-suggestions) Clearly you *didn't* do your research.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From what I've understood Software Recommendations have had to be extra strict to try to keep the site under some sort of control. If we suddenly give them a few hundred questions a day from SO the site is certainly going to crumble. For this reason alone I don't think it's a very good idea.

Furthermore, I don't think I've ever seen a software recommendation question which I would feel comfortable giving to another site. If it's a crap question it's a crap question and we shouldn't be migrating crap.

To address your custom close reason, you don't appear to have an account on Software Recommendations. This would usually be an indication that you're less qualified to suggest people move their questions there. Unless you have an account I would be very careful about suggesting it - read their help centre and some highly voted questions (open) and be doubly certain that you know you're right. Even better don't comment and ask a member of the site what they think.

Comment: _If it's a crap question it's a crap question and we shouldn't be migrating crap._ this about cover any and all migrations from SO

Comment: I've got some rep on SF and DBA.SE so it works sometimes @bluefeet! Just, not that often...

Comment: A question that is *crap* on SO because it asks for a *library* can be perfectly *valid* on the Software Recommendations site.

Answer (score 21):

SR mod here.

This is not going to happen soon for a few reasons:

1. **We don't migrate crap.** Most SO questions that get closed with that reason don't fit [our quality guidelines](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information), and thus would be closed on SR.
2. **SO is huge.** SR is small. If we allowed any 4/5 close voters to toss SO questions over the fence to us... I can only imagine. Ugh. *Plus*, the type of people that ask software recommendation questions on SO aren't likely to read our rules *either*, so... yeah.

Looking at SR's migration stats, we've had a grand total of four migrations from SO. And even with mods being the only ones that can migrate, one of them was *still* rejected.

Comment: 4/5 might be too much, but 1/5 might be OK. A grand total of four migrations from SO is clearly not enough. We could take much more questions. Actually, we would argue we would be able to absorb all of it if crap is filtered out correctly (which might require a bit of training I agree, but I trust that SO mods are able to understand SR).

Comment: In regards to point #2, the site has graduated. The post could be amended to reflect that, however I still think that the overall feeling stands.

Answer (score 6):

SE has made it clear that there won't be a specific close reason for SR or a migration path to it while it's still in beta.  If/when it becomes a graduated site we can begin *considering* it.

Comment: SR is apparantly graduating from Beta.  http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/2298/101

Answer (score -6):

The whole concept of SR is flawed.  If I want advice about a photo application, I want to ask to other photographers.  If I want to know which API I want to ask programmer geeks.  Most of the photographers don't hang out on SR.  Ditto most of the programmer geeks.  SR has an eclectic mix of people few of which are experienced in any given software topic.

The better answer is to make a 'software recommendation' tag and a modification of SE's software that  you can block by tag if you aren't interested in it.  Software recommendations should be answered by the largest collection of people in SE space that use that software, not by a conglomerate made from a few each of many exchanges.

At this point one of the requirements for a SR would be that the author compare at least two packages.  Sure it's still going to be biased, and opinionated.  So is life.

I participate in SR.  MOstly asking for recommendations that never get answered.  Look at the ratio of unanswered to accepted answer on that site, and compare to others.

Comment: Well, this is very much not the correct place to argue for this viewpoint. SR has graduated: it is highly unlikely to ever be shut down, and the duplication of effort in setting up good answering practices around a *meta-tag* here on SO (of all places) would be very strongly disliked by SE staff and the majority of experienced users on SO and SR both. SR, being a different site, has a much easier time enforcing its unique quality requirements, while meta tags are presently wildly unsuitable for the purpose.

Comment: All that said, if you *do* want to argue for shutting down SR in favor of an SO meta-tag, you'll absolutely need to ask a new question with a ton of research and backup arguments and preemptive answers for every objection likely to be raised. Not sure whether MSE or MSO would be the least worst place for this.