# How to discourage off-topic questions asking for off-site resources?

Tags: discussion

I feel frustrated by what I see as a skirting of the rules due to the low attention given to certain off topic questions.

It seems like quite often, someone will ask for some off site resource in a clear cut violation of our rules. Any person with close vote powers should know in a heartbeat that these questions aren't allowed. Worse - other users (often low rep) will come along and answer the question, either with an actual answer or in the comments. Those actions only serve to ensure that the next time the OP wants a tool recommendation they'll come back to SO.

Actions I take

- downvote the question  (my downvote usually has no effect because they're low reputation or don't care about reputation, and the person that answers will upvote - more than offsetting my downvote. This *rewards the person* breaking the rules!)
- vote to close as off topic
- leave a comment explaining it's not allowed, and notify anyone that attempts to answer the question that it's not a good idea to answer these types of questions.

But it's often too little, too late. The OP gets what they want, and no consequences are seen for skirting the rules

If I didn't have vote to close privileges, I would flag the question which would put in the Close Votes review queue. But I can no longer flag the question for that reason, only vote. Does voting to close also put it in the Close Votes review queue as if I had flagged it?

What can be done in these situations to discourage users from asking these questions in the future?

Two example questions (that have since been downvoted and closed due to Meta effect):

- [How to search for book details with a book api for c# asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29394781)
- [Need Articles about how to learn ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308932)

Comment: Close voting puts the post in the review queue too. Most such offtopic posts are from first-time offenders, in my experience a downvote and a close vote are working just fine to deter repeats.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I have no specific research to back this up - but my gut feeling is that if these questions don't receive enough attention - like the two I described if they hadn't been mentioned here - won't have any consequences, and thus the users end up being encouraged to become repeat offenders because they got the answer they want and they got rewarded for asking the question. Perhaps I should do some more research to back my theory up that it encourages repeat offenders.

Comment: Bad examples for your theory. One user has 27 questions, one duplicate, no others closed than the example. The other use answered a question before asking their first, and has answered one since, and has an accept.

Comment: @BillWoodger You can't discount my theory by proving that some people don't become repeat offenders. I would expect *some* people to take the rules seriously if they didn't know about them and to become "good" users. In order to prove or disprove my theory, we need to find a lot of examples of repeat offenders (to prove) or find very few examples of repeat offenders (to disprove).

Comment: Where did I say I was discounting it? It has been referenced before. There are also two behaviours, those of askers, and answerers. And the answerers are in two groups, those with answers, and those in comments.

Comment: @BillWoodger it seems to me you're discounting it by saying those are bad examples - but they weren't meant to be examples of repeat offenders. Sorry if misunderstood - can you clarify what your point is?

Comment: Simply saying your examples don't support you. Now, do you find users who have asked multiple offtopic questions and keep getting satisfied with answers or comments? Or, does the practice encourage other, unconnected, new users to ask such questions because they've seen them before. If you can spot the first, there may be a case. How would you spot the second. Whose behaviour needs to change? Askers, or the two types of answerer?

Comment: Personally, I've been busted a couple of times for discouraging answers to off-topic questions (nothing major, just mod removing my comments) :-)

Comment: @BillWoodger. I don't think they're bad examples - one of them was several days old. For your questions, I believe they're logically true, but I need to find evidence of that in practice.

Comment: related: [Clean up “looking for \[something\]” questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/282932/839601)

Comment: Do you downvote the answers on those questions?

Comment: @BSMP Yes, to discourage people from rewarding those that break the rules.

Comment: @pnuts Discouraging people from rewarding those that break the rules is *not* personal. I don't care who's doing it, I'm not going to remember the name or hold a grudge or hope to do emotional harm. I simply want a system where they're not rewarded for encouraging the wrong things, and where they're held responsible (in some format) for encouraging the wrong things

Comment: @pnuts Downvoting is a mechanism used to show people that their answer should not be posted. If an answer is to a question that's off topic, that answer doesn't belong on this site, useful though it might be to someone. It's outside the scope of SO. Though yes, I rather like your idea that we might be able to vote to remove (delete? hide?) answers in limited circumstances without needing to be a moderator. That would cause the poster to lose any earned reputation from that answer. That would give us another effective tool to prevent encouraging these types of questions.

Comment: It's not clear to me why such questions are discouraged. An education campaign might be a better idea than improved enforcement.

Comment: @Jesdisciple The people that are breaking this rule are unlikely to look for education. I suggest you start with reading about [what's on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), as it includes a small explanation why. If that's still not enough, ask a new question on Meta (after searching to see if someone else has asked a similar question).

Comment: @mason I'm familiar with that page, but it has never satisfied me as far as how opinionated answers are harmful. I've long considered that very misguided and legalistic, and if I need a programming tool SO still seems an appropriate place to ask. That I could lose rep for doing so is unfortunate. A Meta question might be forthcoming.

Comment: @Jesdisciple Like I said, read the [existing material](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255468/opinion-based-questions) on the topic before starting a new discussion.

Comment: Whoa, don't we now have a SE site just for recommendations?  I'd think that posting that we have a website for those questions would be the most effectively way to teach users about this! See http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @BlackVegetable mentioned SoftwareRecs.SE. If that gets out of beta we can just vote to migrate. (Can posts be migrated to beta sites?)

Comment: @AlexA. If they can't be migrated to beta sites, they should. It would increase awareness of the beta site.

Comment: @mason: It's probably by design that posts can't (to my knowledge) be migrated to beta sites just in case the site falls by the wayside.

Answer (score 11):

There is nothing that you can change till SO will continue encourage asking such questions. Yes, it is written that they are off topic, it is written that you should not ask them and sometimes they are even got closed.

But the main point is that it is super beneficial in terms of the reputation to ask and to answer them. And till it will be, there always will be users who would want to do this.

I am active in mongo tab, and here is a couple of questions which are clearly off topic:

- [When to use CouchDB over MongoDB and vice versa](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12437790/1090562) with **370 / 331** question upvoted, highest answer upvotes
- [MongoDB vs. Cassandra](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2892729/1090562) **302 / 281**
- [When to Redis? When to MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5400163/1090562) **172 / 120**

There is nothing wrong about mongo, questions like these are in every tag.

Why is it beneficial? Because hoards of first time users, will eventually upvote it. So in the long run asking these off-topic questions will pay of. Yes, you might get a couple of downvotes, but looking ahead you will get far too many upvotes.

A good rule of thumb - whenever a new popular thing arrive - just ask an offtopic question about it. Do not trust me?

Swift arrived and boom [swift vs objective](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24026367/1090562), [should I learn swift](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25751738/1090562). Yes, it got closed, but the points will be collected. Oh, there is a new react framework so why not to ask an offtopic react stuff [react vs angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27587364/1090562). If you want more examples - just google for `popularThing1 vs popularThing2 stackoverflow`.

No matter how fast will be moderators, no matter how many times a couple of users will try to downvote/close off topic questions, it will always be beneficial to ask them and answer till the rules are the same.

So change the rules and behavior will change.

Comment: I'm thinking a change more along the lines of "if you have X amount of reputation, it only takes 3 votes to close a question asking for off-site resources."

Comment: related: [Stack Overflow technology makes me write bad answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/171172/165773)

Comment: Keep in mind that your examples are several years old (the oldest is nearly 5 years old). In that time, the definition of "on-topic" has changed significantly.

Comment: @jdb 5 years old? Look at the years: questions are 2012, 2010, 2011. And 2014 and 2014. Sorry that 2014 year old question/answer was not able to collect 200 upvotes, but wait till 2017 and it will.

Comment: @SalvadorDali - The "recommend or find a tool" close reason was created in mid 2013, *after* your highlighted examples. Your other examples have all been closed except for angular vs react (which was actually an answerable question, if not a bit broad in scope). It was **not** a recommendation question, however. With the changes to the on-topic policies, it is unlikely that recommendation questions will get the same level of rep that they used to.

Comment: @jdb most of the question fall into category: "primary opinion based". As for will they get the same amount of upvotes: I highly doubt they will get as much as 200 (not because of the policy, just because people tend to upvote less these days), but they will still get more than average.

Comment: Totally agree.  Here we are 7 years later and the rules have unfortunately still not changed to change the bad behavior.

Answer (score 10):

Sure, often enough, questions like that get an answer.

*However*, more often than not, such questions are also significantly downvoted and / or closed.
Should asking questions like that become a habit for that user, he will rake up more and more downvotes / closed questions, hurting their reputation and ability to post new questions.

Simply said, repeat offenders will eventually get a question ban.

Aside from the actions you're already taking, there's not much else you can do.

Comment: "there's not much else you can do." That's what I take issue with - there should be an easier mechanism for these clear cut situations so we need fewer high rep community members to see them.

Comment: Question ban. Oooh. And it's so hard to create a new account.   Swing that banhammer, and everybody goes "Oooh!".  :-)

Comment: Still, it's [not always necessary to close off-topic questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254402/is-closing-old-questions-a-gigantic-waste-of-time-and-effort/254404#254404) if they aren't causing any problems on the site.

Comment: @AndersonGreen: I don't quite agree. The fact that they're OT is a problem.

Answer (score 7):

I mentioned this in a comment, but shouldn't we (perhaps in addition to other actions) be giving a link to the proper place for these questions? Namely: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ ?

I'd think the positive reinforcement will please new/old users, will boost the new site's traffic, and encourage awareness that we don't post recommendations for off-site tools on *this* website.

EDIT: This should really only apply to well-written recommendation questions; otherwise we may just be dooming another website!

Comment: True, would be good to tell them about that in the case of software reccomendations, but that of course doesn't work for tutorials or books. A comment you can reuse- `Asking for us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource is not allowed on Stack Overflow. You may be able to find the information you seek on our [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) beta site.`

Comment: Ah, that is a good point.  Now we just need an SE site for tutorial recommendations! ;)

Comment: Even recommending that site might be [a bad idea](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252784/should-we-change-the-software-recs-ot-reason-to-point-to-the-software-recs-se/252786#252786).  And so is [migrating there](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221970/changed-response-to-recommendation-questions/222018#222018).

Comment: @ryanyuyu Ah, forgive me. I am newly exposed to that website. I guess the quality of the recommendation question should be a factor for sure!

Comment: @BlackVegetable no worries.  I've run into a similar thing being too eager to migrate to places like code review.  That's what the meta is for at any rate.  Getting advice and learning from other users on the proper thing to do.

Answer (score 3):

Off-site resource questions should *certainly* be down-voted, and closed ASAP. Ideally, they get closed without any answers and thus will soon be auto-deleted.

I suppose it could be seen as encouraging such questions if they receive helpful advice even in a comment. OTOH, I imagine that getting your question put on hold can be pretty discouraging, especially to new members, so I generally try to make *some* sort of helpful comment when I close-vote. I don't want new members to feel unwelcome, and I don't want to appear like some sort of fascist that goes around stomping on newbies who are innocently asking off-topic questions.

Sure, giving a complete answer in a comment to a question that's likely to be closed is probably not a good idea, but I don't see the harm in just giving a helpful hint (possibly even including a link).

Comment: I'd advice against answering questions that you downvote / closevote. Don't encourage someone to post bad questions. Teach them our ways, instead.

Comment: @Cerbrus that is so true. So often did I not answer the question only later to see that another (often high rep) user post the obvious one-line answer and gets off with it. But surely, there must be a reason why these users have so much more reputation then me ;).

Comment: @Cerbrus: I _try_ not to give a full answer in my comments, just a helpful hint. When appropriate I may explain why the question is off-topic (if the on-hold message is too general), and / or direct them to a relevant Help page, encouraging them to make a better question next time.